# Inno Setup rename file if component selected

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to rename a file IF  a component is selected, or full install selected. But having some issues.

When I run it I get the error:

```
Line 55;
Column 5;
Identifier expected;
```

Which would be the `procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);` line below.

```
[Code]
function GetFileName(const AFileName: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{app}\' + AFileName);
end;

procedure AfterInstallProc;
begin
  If IsComponentSelected('update') or IsComponentSelected('full') then
  begin
    procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
    begin
      if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
      begin
        if not FileExists(GetFileName('update.old.dat')) then
          RenameFile(GetFileName('update.dat'), GetFileName('update.old.dat'));
      end;
    end;
  else
    result := true;
  end;
end;
```

Mind you I got these bits of code from searching for my questions here. I'm not sure I am performing it correctly. Got some errors fixed like selecting components but now it seems procedure to rename files is wrong?

Comment: The part where you are calling `IsComponentSelected` function is correct, but for some reason you've tried to inline an event method into your code. That is not possible to do. Either you can write a handler for the `CurStepChanged` or make an after install procedure.

Comment: Ok. So I'm confused. What is CurStepChanged? Is it necessary in this instance? Basically it's just one file that needs to be renamed if a update was applied as well.

Comment: `CurStepChanged` method is an event method, method which is called when Inno Setup starts or finishes a certain step. And yes, for this case is good to write a `CurStepChanged` event handler for the `ssInstall` step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this instead:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) and (IsComponentSelected('full') or
    IsComponentSelected('update')) then
  begin
    if not FileExists(GetFileName('update.old.dat')) then
      RenameFile(GetFileName('update.dat'), GetFileName('update.old.dat'));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome it works, but it's not renaming the fie. Does this not account for sub directories and extensions? For example would I need to do `Result := ExpandConstant('{app}db\' + AFileName);` to account for a subdir? And not sure about extensions.

Comment: It works as written. You are checking if there is no `update.old.dat` file in the application directory and if there is no such file, you rename the `update.dat` file (which must exist of course) to `update.old.dat`. For `db` subdirectory write `Result := ExpandConstant('{app}\db\' + AFileName);`.

Comment: Gotchya! Thanks! I had my checking logic backwards.